# Laravel syntax error due to nonaggregated column with select DB:raw and GROUP BY

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, laravel-query-builder, mysql-error-1055

I have the following 4 SQL tables:

**studios**
integer id
string name
integer last_movie_id

**movies**
integer id
integer studio_id
string type

**actor_movie**
integer movie_id
integer actor_id

**actors**
integer id
string name

I'm trying to build a query that gives me for a specific actor, the list of the studios he worked for, including the last movie of the studio (wether the actor played in it or not):

- name of the studio
- date of the last movie from this studio
- type of the last movie from this studio

My code is the following (in ActorController):

```
$actor = \App\Actor::findOrFail($id);
$studios = \DB::table('actor_movie')
            ->leftjoin('movies', 'actor_movie.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
            ->leftjoin('studios', 'studios.id', '=', 'movies.studio_id')
            ->select(
                'studios.name',
                'studios.last_movie_date'
                \DB::raw('(SELECT movies.type FROM movies WHERE movies.id = studios.last_movie_id') as type')
            ->where('actor_movie.actor_id', $actor->id)
            ->groupBy('studios.name', 'studios.last_movie_date', 'type')
            ->get();
```

But I have the following error: 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column [...] this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I don't want to set the sql_strict_mode to false in order to circumvent this error. I would like to understand what's wrong with my query. I tried using aggregation functions like "ANY_VALUE" but nothing worked out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Wouldn't `movies.type` with an additional join condition work without the need of a nested select in the select (which is really rally ugly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the query wrongly - specifically

`\DB::raw('(SELECT movies.type FROM movies WHERE movies.id = studios.last_movie_id') as type` which is in `select` statement. This query gives you **value(s)** not `COLUNM NAME` which should be in `select` statement like `select col1Name, col2Name, .... from ....`.

As you did not provide full table structures & relation(i.e-you mentioned studios.last_movie_date in query but not in question) it is very hard for anyone to give you correct query but the below should work fine -

```
$actor = \App\Actor::findOrFail($id);
$studios = \DB::table('actor_movie')
            ->leftjoin('movies', 'actor_movie.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
            ->leftjoin('studios', 'studios.id', '=', 'movies.studio_id')
            ->leftjoin('movies as mov2', 'studios.last_movie_id', '=', 'mov2.id')
            ->select(
                'studios.name',
                'studios.last_movie_date',
                'mov2.type'
                )
            ->where('actor_movie.actor_id', $actor->id)
            ->groupBy('studios.name', 'studios.last_movie_date', 'type')
            ->get();
```

For other queries I think you got the idea.

> How would I do it -

create a migration for below query -

```
create view actors_studio as 
select am.actor_id, mov.studio_id, std.name as studio_name, std.last_mov_id, mov2.type as last_mov_type
from actor_movie as am
left join movies as mov on am.movie_id = mov.id
left join studios as std on std.id = mov.studio_id
left join movies as mov2 on std.last_movie_id = mov2.id
group by  actor_id, studio_id, studio_name, last_mov_id, last_mov_type
order by actor_id, studio_id;
```

Then run the migrate command and then create a model for view `actors_studio` i.e `VwActorStudios` and then a simple query

```
$studios = VwActorStudios::where('actor_id', $actor->id)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding a second join with the movie table was the right thing to do ! Perfect, thank you !